# Enabling traffic layer in com.google.android.maps.MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I know that com.google.android.maps.MapView is deprecated by google but i would like to ask is it possible to enable the traffic layer in my app using MapView?

Comment: Why don't you just migrate do V2?

Comment: I will but it will take me a while cause its a complex project and i was looking a way to use it until i migrate to V2.

Comment: Once try with this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/31658658/5567009

Comment: In you link GoogleMap is used, i use MapView

Comment: no way, you have to update your project to V2. Traffic integration has not been developed by google for old V1 maps, and that layer is not open and freely available