# Does Google map support INRIX traffic data?

Tags: android, google-maps, dictionary, openstreetmap

I am developing the app with google map and I want to implement the INRIX traffic in google map. So I just want to know that if the Google map support INRIX traffic data.

Comment: It is probably not possible with google, except they already use it ;). But maybe other tools like open source tools work. Do you have INRIX data? Or why this specific data?

Comment: Karussel is correct as to it may not be possible to integrate with google. As a workaround you can try using [setTrafficEnabled](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#public-methods) or [isTrafficEnabled](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#public-methods) a . For more [info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31657822/how-can-i-include-the-traffic-layer-of-google-maps) check this link to see some implementation. Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for reply. It save my time.